# Can't run sinatra as a .class file

Tags: ruby, sinatra, jruby

I'm trying to run a sinatra "Hello World" as a compiled class file with jruby.

It is working when I'm running it interpretet, but as a .class file I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- rubygems
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:966)
    at RUBY.<top>(index.rb:1)
```

Here is the source code:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/hello/:name' do
  "Hello #{params['name']}"
end
```

Here is how I compiled and executed it:

```
jruby -S jrubyc index.rb
java -cp .;C:\dev\lang\ruby\jruby-9.0.0.0.pre2\lib\jruby.jar index
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the "complete" jruby-complete.jar ... as it might NOT use the file-system JRuby layout files when started using `java`. also you probably want to look at Warbler to make sure everything needed gets packed (e.g. sinatra has a gem rack dependency etc.)

alternatively you can try using `jruby index` or `jruby index.class`

Comment: I tried Warblar and it seems to compile, but when I try to run the jar it gives me nothing but the following message: `io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated`. Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: that is just a warning [from](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/3485ab608b89dc31e7de71493f719a93d168900e/lib/ruby/stdlib/io/console.rb#L207) RbConfig ... not sure it matters much